# XML Schema 1.1 Attribute Grouping Constraints

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

In using XML Schema 1.1, I'd like to define an attribute group that occurs entirely together, i.e. all the attributes in the attributeGroup are either present or not-present.  In the following example, I'd like `<anelement>` to have both attributes (`attr_one` and `attr_two`) present or neither attribute present, never only a single attribute present.

```
<attributeGroup name="attrgroup">
  <attribute name="attr_one" />
  <attribute name="attr_one" />
</attributeGroup>

<element name="anelement">
  <complexType>
    <attributeGroup ref="attrgroup" />
  </complexType>
</element>
```

As I understand it, XML Schema 1.0 cannot specify these attribute relationships (correct?).  What is the best way to specify them in XSD 1.1?  I figure that I can use `assert` to specify the relationship, something like the following:

```
<element name="anelement">
  <complexType>
    <attributeGroup ref="attrgroup" />
    <assert test="(@attr_one and @attr_two) or not(@attr_one or @attr_two)" />
  </complexType>
</element>
```

But I was hoping there was something added to 1.1 that would allow me to specify the relationship using the existing language, e.g. a `use` attribute on `attributeGroup`s.  What is the best way to specify this relationship in XML Schema 1.1?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know XML Schema 1.1 provided for asserts like that.

Comment: What implementation of XML Schema 1.1 are you using? Saxon?

Comment: Yeah, 1.1. has full XPath assertions.  Xerces-J has support for all the parts of 1.1 that I want to use, so I'm using it for validation at the moment.  Hopefully other tools (especially OXMs) will catch up soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions are the way to do this. A simpler formulation is

```
test="exists(@attr_one) = exists(@attr_two)"
```

or you could do

```
test="count(@attr_one|@attr_two) != 1"
```

Comment: Thanks, thats about what I thought.  Any ideas how to extrapolate your simpler formulations to N number of attributes without getting much more complex?